# error creating a new user inside coverage test for django

Tags: django-models

I need to create a user inside a coverage test of a view and I am trying this but it is not working:

```
request.user = User.objects.create_(
        username='admin', email='admin@sura.com', password='eagle0002')
```

What did I miss?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this :

```
request.user = User.objects.create_user(
        username='admin', email='admin@sura.com', password='eagle0002')
```

Hope it helps